# Why are our SharePoint Online list customizations lost inside the SharePoint mobile app?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, mobile, powerapps-forms

I have a SharePoint Online team site and we made these modifications to it's lists:-

1. I have customized the list's forms (new,edit and display) using power-app.
2. inside another list i set a default value for an field as follow:-

[image]

3. in another list i set some field to be hidden inside the sharepoint list;s forms as follow:-

[image]

The above modifications are working well in web browsers, but when we accessed the lists inside sharepoint mobile app, all those modifications will be lost! so how i can force sharepoint mobile app to respect the above customization?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint mobile app list features are limited comparing to the options available through browser. There are multiple requests through User Voice forum, links below, and the feature you are after, is in the plans, not sure when it will be available though.

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/350433-sharepoint-mobile-app-for-ios/suggestions/15874830-list-view

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/540331-sharepoint-mobile-app-for-android/suggestions/17507017-make-list-view-more-informative

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/350433-sharepoint-mobile-app-for-ios/status/1459504

Comment: good to know that others have already reported this.. meanwhile is there anyway of customizing the mobile app forms?